# [].append(foo) idiom

Tags: python, idioms

**Edited to add: Drat it! I didn't have the latest version of the code. It was a bug and he fixed it. Please join me in voting to close.**

I'm looking at somebody else's Python code that says:

```
bar = [].append(foo)
```

I believe this is an overly complicated way of saying the same as :

```
bar = [foo]
```

I wondered if he was simply ignorant of the Python syntax, but generally his Python code seems quite competent and in another place in the code, he has written:

```
qux(param=[foo])
```

So, that doesn't explain it.

Am I missing something? Is this a useful idiom I am not aware of? (e.g. it is more performant, works on older versions of Python, etc.)

Comment: list.append returns None, not the list. I'd guess it's a bug.

Comment: In Python 2.7, anyway, this doesn't work. `bar = [].append(foo)` leaves `bar` as `None`.

Comment: There is no situation in which that code makes sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it is an overly complicated way of saying `bar = None`. List methods operate in-place, and hence return `None`.